# bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5 failed, cannot satisfy x11 although feature was removed

Tags: qt, arm, toolchain, yocto, qt5.4

Building Qt5 toolchain for Raspberry Pi2 Qt apps using Yocto `fido` [See this tutorial](http://www.embarcados.com.br/raspberry-pi-2-qt5-qt-creator-yocto-fido/). My build machine is NUC with Debian 7.8.

Succeeded to build my image perfectly, but getting error while building my toolchain.

my `local.conf`, I removed `x11` feature

```
MACHINE = "raspberrypi2"
LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST="commercial license"

DISTRO = "poky"
DL_DIR = "${TOPDIR}/../dl"
PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_ipk"
DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "x11 wayland"   <========= 
# Set Rpi GPU Memory to 128MB
GPU_MEM = "128"
```

my `bblayers.conf`

```
# LAYER_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly

LCONF_VERSION = "6"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
    ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-embarcados \
    ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-embarcados/meta-rpi \
    ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-qt5 \
    ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-raspberrypi \
    ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
    ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-openembedded/meta-ruby \
    ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta \
    ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-yocto \
  "
```

I have tried from scratch by removing my `build/tmp` folder to no avail, I am still getting the `x11` dependency issue although it's a removed feature in my `local.conf`.

```
ERROR: Unable to install packages. Command '/home/otto/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/opkg-cl -f /home/otto/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-vfpv4-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/opkg.conf -o /home/otto/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-vfpv4-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/sdk/image/opt/poky/1.8/sysroots/cortexa7hf-vfp-vfpv4-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi --force_postinstall --prefer-arch-to-version   install packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target-dbg packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target' returned 255:
Installing packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target-dbg (1.0-r8) on root.
Downloading file:/home/otto/yocto/build/tmp/deploy/ipk/all/packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target-dbg_1.0-r8_all.ipk.
```

and

```
Configuring glibc-gconv-cp1252.
Configuring libsegfault.
Configuring libgcov-dev.
Configuring glibc-gconv-iso8859-15.
Configuring glibc-gconv-iso8859-1.
Configuring packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target.
Collected errors:
 * satisfy_dependencies_for: Cannot satisfy the following dependencies for packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target:
 *  libx11-6 (>= 1.6.2) *   libxcb1 (>= 1.11) *     libxau6 (>= 1.0.8) *    libxdmcp6 (>= 1.1.1) * 
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target.

ERROR: Function failed: do_populate_sdk
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/otto/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-vfpv4-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_populate_sdk.26687
ERROR: Task 7 (/home/otto/yocto/build/../poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/meta/meta-toolchain-qt5.bb, do_populate_sdk) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3419 tasks of which 3418 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
No currently running tasks (3418 of 3420)

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/otto/yocto/build/../poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/meta/meta-toolchain-qt5.bb, do_populate_sdk
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Any pointers on how to resolve this? why would it still try to compile `x11` feature when removed?

(Votes down are Ok, but a comment explaining why you are voting down is better. It's not like I am not trying hard on my side to resolve this critical issue on a Sunday! There is definitely some trolls in the StackExchange community)

### Libraries on build machine

This look to be the problem, the installed version is `1.5.0-1+deb7u2` where it requires `>=1.6.2`. That doesn't answer my question, but that's a hint.

```
otto@marvin:~/yocto/build$ apt-cache policy libx11-6
libx11-6:
  Installed: 2:1.5.0-1+deb7u2
  Candidate: 2:1.5.0-1+deb7u2
  Version table:
 *** 2:1.5.0-1+deb7u2 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:1.5.0-1+deb7u1 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages

otto@marvin:~/yocto/build$ apt-cache policy libxcb1
libxcb1:
  Installed: 1.8.1-2+deb7u1
  Candidate: 1.8.1-2+deb7u1
  Version table:
     1.10-3~bpo70+1 0
        100 http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy-backports/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.8.1-2+deb7u1 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

otto@marvin:~/yocto/build$ apt-cache policy libxau6
libxau6:
  Installed: 1:1.0.7-1
  Candidate: 1:1.0.7-1
  Version table:
 *** 1:1.0.7-1 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

otto@marvin:~/yocto/build$ apt-cache policy libxdmcp6
libxdmcp6:
  Installed: 1:1.1.1-1
  Candidate: 1:1.1.1-1
  Version table:
 *** 1:1.1.1-1 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

## Upgraded to Debian 8.1 but problem persists

although `libx11-6`, `libxau6`, `libxdmcp6` satisfy the version requirements, one library doesn't, and I can't install `>=1.11` (I think), this is the [latest `libxcb1` on Jessie](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libxcb1) that I can get.

```
otto@marvin:~/yocto$ sudo apt-cache policy libxcb1
libxcb1:
  Installed: 1.10-3+b1
  Candidate: 1.10-3+b1
  Version table:
 *** 1.10-3+b1 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

the message

```
Configuring packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target.
Collected errors:
 * satisfy_dependencies_for: Cannot satisfy the following dependencies for packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target:
 *  libx11-6 (>= 1.6.2) *   libxcb1 (>= 1.11) *     libxau6 (>= 1.0.8) *    libxdmcp6 (>= 1.1.1) * 
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target.

ERROR: Function failed: do_populate_sdk
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/otto/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-vfpv4-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_populate_sdk.12273
ERROR: Task 7 (/home/otto/yocto/build/../poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/meta/meta-toolchain-qt5.bb, do_populate_sdk) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3419 tasks of which 3418 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
No currently running tasks (3418 of 3420)

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/otto/yocto/build/../poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/meta/meta-toolchain-qt5.bb, do_populate_sdk
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

### Identified failing command

```
/home/otto/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/opkg-cl -f /home/otto/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-vfpv4-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/opkg.conf -o /home/otto/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-vfpv4-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/sdk/image/opt/poky/1.8/sysroots/cortexa7hf-vfp-vfpv4-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi --force_postinstall --prefer-arch-to-version install packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target
```

definitely something in the `packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target`

Comment: Did you check installation requirement for yocto fido ?

Comment: Could you post the packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target.bb?  I do not see any problem from the one in github.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to the experience I had where I built for **X11** then subsequently turned it off with `DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "x11"`.

As far as I could see there was still a dependency on **X11** somewhere in the *license manifest*, from what I recall there was a header file used `Xauth` in `pango/cairo` that's stubbed out without **X11**.

The problem went away when I built for a different `MACHINE`, so I would suggest launching a completely fresh build without X11 after clearing your `SSTATE_CACHE`.

Comment: Please be more clear as to what needs to be done to fix the problem, and how the OP can do this. Your subsequent decisions are probably irrelevant to the solution and should probably be left out.

Comment: whoopy thank you for sharing your insight and experience. I can't believe someone voted down your help.